# Binding View and ViewModel on a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I'm using a View and ViewModel set on an already existing ViewModel. You could say that's the base with the second ViewModel placed on that.

When placing another ViewModel in the underlying ViewModel of `MainViewModel` (`BrowseViewModel` in this particular sample), the associated ViewModel does not show up.

Implementation as follows:

```
class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private BrowseViewModel _BrowseViewModel= new BrowseViewModel();

    public BrowseViewModel BrowseViewModel
    {
        get { return _BrowseViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_BrowseViewModel== value) return;
            _BrowseViewModel= value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("BrowseViewModel");
        }
    }
}

class BrowseViewModel: PropertyChangedBase
{
    private ListingViewModel _ListingViewModel = new ListingViewModel();
    public ListingViewModel ListingViewModel
    {
        get { return ListingViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_ListingViewModel == value) return;
            _ListingViewModel = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("ListingViewModel");
        }
    }
}

ListingViewModel...
```

(I clipped of the non-relevant code here)

Implementation in my markup (MainView):

```
<ContentControl x:Name="BrowseViewModel"/>
```

and in `BrowseView`:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <ContentControl x:Name="ListingViewModel"/>
      </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

I experienced the exact same problem today when adding another ViewModel to an existing underlying ViewModel of the `MainViewModel`. If I dont have a underlying ViewModel and if I'm using the current `MainViewModel`, everything works appropriately.

**Note:** I told Caliburn to look for Views and their ViewModels at the previously named namespaces, that is no issue.

Comment: How are you coding up the MainView to show your TestControlView? Can you give us an example (XAML)  I have an idea but to confirm it...

Comment: @mvermef There you go. I updated my question and included some real names in order to make things clear. I should have said that I'm using this `ViewModel` on a `DataGrid`, however I provided that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're binding something to a DataGrid in BrowseView correct?

Declaring something like

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ListingViewModel"/>
```

is the shorthand version of declaring

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ListingViewModel" />
```

Therefore I'm assuming (it's been a while since I've worked in WPF) that the DataContext in the RowDetailsTemplate is not BrowseViewModel but whatever you're binding to the DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I actually think that the binding between the MainViewModel and the BrowseViewModel is incorrect in one way or another. This problem occurs on every underlying ViewModel, not only the one with the DataGrid. Any thoughts on how I may debug that properly?

Comment: yes you can debug using Logging which can be setup via just doing console output to show you how things are coming together. GamingLibrary has a sample of this in the samples

Comment: yea I completely forgot to ask if something in the contents of the data grid would produce this?  What does the model look like on the datagrid, cause if it doesn't incorporate anything of BrowserViewModel then it will never show ListingViewModel items

Comment: @mvermef Yep, that was one of the causes but the View is still hiding from me. As stated above, I'm assuming that the binding is incorrect or I need to implement any other feature. Stumbled across `Screen` but that is not what I want since my controls are only loaded once and therefore need no dynamic management.

Comment: What's currently being bound to the ItemsSource your DataGrid? This will tell us what the DataContext inside the RowDetailsTemplate is.

Comment: A collection of `ItemModel`. Well, I think that we're on the right track. If I need this specific ViewModel for each `ItemModel`, would it be legal to create a ViewModel instance in every `ItemModel`? As for me, this sounds quite against the rules of the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Yep, just tested the binding and indeed, it was wrong due to the ItemsSource of the DataGrid. Saved my day, thanks @NigelSampson !

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Context="BrowseView" cal:View.Model="BrowseViewModel" />
```

this should get your BrowseView and bind accordingly, since MainViewModel holds BrowseViewModel prop it should bind correctly.  This assumes `<ProjectName>.Views.BrowseView` namespace and `<ProjectName>.ViewModels.BrowseViewModel`, likewise with ListingViewModel

Comment: What exactly is the difference when binding per name and per `cal:View.Context/Model`? I did that like you described but Caliburn says, that it can't locate any instances of BrowseViewModel. Though I setup the namespaces and Caliburn correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: the difference is you specifying directly that this is the view and model that you want on this contentcontrol.  where as using the naming method inside the datatemplate, may not find the viewmodel due to a visual tree issue with templating which I have seen before but it was related to a context menu being embedded in the listview.  You could try x:Name="BrowserViewModel" since that is the name of your ViewModel but I don't think it will work.  To be completely honest never tried embedding a contentcontrol in the datatemplate within a datagrid.

Comment: most view switching is done with the <ContentControl cal:View.Context="{Binding SomeStringPropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" cal:View.Model="{Binding}" /> does the binding on the parent view model that is currently the datacontext but it can be changed since all of the context/model items are just string soup for location.

Comment: Well, the main issue is, that it actually works when I bind a ViewModel to my MainViewModel as I did in the starting post. The problem is, that binding yet another ViewModel to the ViewModel bound to the MainViewModel does not work because it does not show up. Did no one ever tried to accomplish that? Weird.

Comment: What container are you using for this? MEF, simplecontainer etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "container"?

Comment: ahh, so you aren't using Dependency Injection / IoC

Comment: Wait a second, I just didn't notice what you are talking about. I'm using `SimpleContainer` as container in my bootstrapper.