# CaliburnMicro Binding View inside RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, contentcontrol, rowdetailstemplate

I have a RadGridView with a GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn, which can expand a selected item and show more Details. I want to use CaliburnMicro to Display the DetailsView, so I add a property of the DetailsViewModel to my "MainViewModel" and add a ContentControl with a Binding to it.

```
 <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Products.View}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"  ... > 

            <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ProductDetailsViewModel}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>


            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn />

                ...Columndefinitions...

            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>                   
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

The problem is, that the Details are not displayed. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035648/binding-view-and-viewmodel-on-a-datagrid) I read that the binding fails because of the ItemsSource. So i tried

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ProductDetailsViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ProductDetailsViewModel` property is the defined in the same class as the `Products` property that the `RadGridView` is bound to, try this:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding DataContext.ProductDetailsViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}" />
```